# hibernate retrive data from multiple tables

Tags: hibernate

I have 3 tables. A,B,C.
A has one to many with B.
B has one to many with C.

Data in tables is,

```
TABLE A
id                 
10
15

TABLE B
id      firstName    AandB_Relation_Key
55       Abc           10
66       Pqr           10
77       xyz           10
88       ddd           15

TABLE C
id       phone_no      CandB_Relation_key
41        44444         77
42        55555         77
43        66666         77
44        88888         66
```

I wanted to retrieve data from Table C depending upon id from Table A in a single query such a way that

if table B has related record in table C , I want to show both records from B and C  otherwise only record from table B(ie here firstName "xyz" has multiple phone nos so i will show xyz = 44444,55555,66666, ddd has no phone no so only ddd)

Currently I am doing as,

a) select all ids from table B where AandB_Relation_Key=id from Table A // its returning all ids from Table B against id from Table A

b) then i m iterating over all ids , taking count from table C against each id as , select count(*) from table C where id= retrieved ids from a)

c) if count > 0    select firstName,phoneNo from table B,C

d) else            select firstName from table B

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select new list(firstName,phone_no) from A left join B left join C where a.id=:id
```

I think that should do it. you will get a list of firstnames with optional phonenumbers.

Comment: umm. check the hibernate documentation, naturally i did not actually test that , but that idea should pretty much work.

Comment: instead of list you can also try map or a class of your own with constructor accepting two strings.

Comment: umm. try changing "a.id" to just "id" , i didnt alias the "A" so it will not see it. but that is basic hql. read the documentation.